# React component props array gets updated when used in a function within the component

Tags: reactjs

I am working with ReactJS and I faced something I don't really know how to solve.

So, I have a component which takes an array of objects as props.
In constructor, I want to modify this array to set the modified version to the state.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const myData = this.processData(data);
    this.state = {
      myData
    };
  }

  static propTypes() {
    return {
      myData: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };
  }
```

Right after statement `const myData = this.processData(data);` if I show the `props.myData` in console, it will already display the modified data, not the original props data!

I read in [this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155899/discussion-between-lowcool-and-garry-taylor) that I should have a cloned array, so that the original one wouldn't be mutated.

So after this the code would look somewhat like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const myData = props.myData;
    const processedData = this.processData(myData);
    this.state = {
       processedData
    };
  }
```

But in the new properties are coming and I am catching them in `componentWillReceiveProps()` - the `nextProps` will be already formatted!

I would appreciate any help, please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not really copying the array by writing `const myData = props.myData;`.
You're just copying its reference to a new variable.

You can use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to make a copy like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const processedData = this.processData(props.myData.slice());
    this.state = {
       processedData
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't seem to work
    `const myData = props.myData;`
    `const myDataProcessed = this.processUsers(myData.slice());`
Same excercise in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`, and I am still getting the modified data.

Comment: Can you provide some information about the `myData` array and how `processUsers` modifies it? `slice` will only return a shallow copy, so nested objects and arrays are still mutated.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I have a complex structure, with nested objects. Okay, will do this for all levels then. Thanks!